# Constructing multiple instances of view residing in SceneDock?

Tags: swift, macos

I've got an NSStackView where I add multiple NSOutlineView instances besides each other. I currently construct those instances from a Nib where I set some options.

I want to replace loading from Nib with an NSOutlineView in SceneDock. I did set all the options I want in my NSOutlineView now part of the SceneDock.

I know I can get access to one instance by creating an IBOutlet inside my NSViewController class. But I need more instances of said NSOutlineView.

I could use the constructors ( init(frame: CGRect) and init(decoder: NSDecoder) ), but I do neither have a fitting frame nor do I have an NSCoder loaded with the settings from the NSOutlineView residing in the SceneDock. Using an empty NSCoder does not load the settings from the NSStoryboard.

How do I get multiple instances of the mentioned NSOutlineView with settings set in NSStoryboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not possible to get more items, because `NSObjects` in `storyboard` are instantiated by the `storyboard` and only `viewControllers` are instantiable from `UIStoryboard/NSStoryboard`. An exception are `cells` created inside `tableViews` inside `viewControllers`, which can be instantiated with `makeView/dequeueReusableCellView`.